# Retrieve all records in steps of 1000 records

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am doing a `dojo.xhrPost` to a URL which gives only 1000 records at a time but I have nearly 2500 records in total.

I want to check the response and if equal to 1000 records I need to do a post again and get the next 1000 records and do the same until the response size is less than 1000.

```
var params = {              
    url: uri,
    handleAs: "json",       
    load: dojo.hitch(this, "onGeoDropDownLoad"),
    error: dojo.hitch(this, "onGeoDropDownError"),
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': null,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    sync: true
};

dojo.xhrPost(params);
```

I am doing something with the response if it is successful like below

```
onGeoDropDownLoad: function(response, ioArgs) {
    console.log("LocateWidget::onGeoDropDownLoad");
    // Processing user specific configuration returned by the server
    if ( response.features ){
    }
}
```

I can see the size of the response by response.features.size.

I can use javascript instead of dojo if I can achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: You are using arcgis js api, the matter here insn't in the xhr request , you have to configure your mapserver of feature server service to return above 1000 recorde in the admin panel .

Comment: Yes, i am using arcgis js api, but i cannot configure the mapserver to return more than 1000 records, can we do anything on our side?

Comment: with js it's impossible , the result is at the server side . so only server config will resolve the issue